# Can I use Ruby version 2.1.2 with Amazon Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am new to AWS and I am trying the tutorial [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html).

I have Ruby 2.1.2 installed but i am a little confused when following step 8 in the above tutorial via the CLI with Eb. I am asked to choose a stack. None of the options are for a version of Ruby greater than 2.0.

Should I use a version of Ruby to satisfy the options given to me or can I use any version of ruby with any stack?

Thanks

Comment: The good thing about aws is that you can build a machine try some stuff and then delete it.  I haven't tried upgrading ruby but there should be no reason why you couldn't do that.  If it doesn't work, just delete it.

Comment: Yeah, I am in the process of downgrading ruby actually and trying that , if anyone knows for sure that would be great.

Comment: @user3507417 Which version of ruby are you trying to downgrade to and on which elastic beanstalk solution stack?

Comment: Hi Rohit, I was looking at ruby version 1.9.3, as that is what the tutorials are based on, and 1.9.3 on 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.4 as the elastic beanstalk stalk. It would be great to have a similar tutorial available for ruby version 2.0.

Comment: I have been able to deploy the sample application at https://console.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/?region=us-west-2#/newApplication?applicationName=RailsSampleApp&solutionStackName=Ruby&sourceBundleUrl=https:%2F%2Fs3.amazonaws.com%2Feb-ruby2-sample%2FRailsSample.zip  using Puma v1.0.5 and ruby v 2.0.0. However, I still don't have an answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently AWS only supports Ruby 1.8.7, 1.9.3, and 2.0.0 from the pre-configured environment types.   However you can customise your own AMI to deploy to your Beanstalk application.

More information here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.customenv.html

Comment: Hi Andrew, ok but I think that customising my own AMI might be too advanced for me at this stage. I am happy that I can't use ruby version 2.1.2 from your answer and from many of my own attempts. Thanks.

Comment: Ruby 2.1.2 now available with elastic beanstalk ... http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2014/08/14/aws-elastic-beanstalk-supports-ruby-2-1/